# Add social media Icons to Elementor mobile Menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, elementor

I`m looking for a solution to adding social media icons to the Elementor-Menu in WordPress. Any Ideas?

I could take a Burger Icon and add a pop up on top, but that would be my last option for me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: does this pen prove any help: [CSS_Grow_hover_Effect](https://codepen.io/AdamCCFC/pen/WvzBKq)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shortcode and use it inside the menu... you will need a code or a plugin to be allow to insert shortcodes in the menu. For example: [Shortcodes in menus](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-in-menus/).

The you can create a shortcode with the elements you want to print, if I'm not wrong as follows, and put it in your functions.php file:

```
function function_whatever()
{ echo 'whatever'; }
add_shortcode('shortcode_whatever', 'function_whatever');
```

And the last thing is to insert the shortcode in the menu:

[shortcode_whatever]

Answer (score 0):

for those who are interested, I solved the whole thing via the wordpress menu, in which I created a menu item for each social media (icon) with an `<img src="/wp-content/uploads/....svg" class="whatever">`, which I then styled.